# Pointwise convergence is uniform convergence under a condition

Tags: real-analysis, riemannian-geometry, normed-spaces, metric-geometry, gromov-hausdorff-limit

[1] [pointwise convergence is uniform convergence under some condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3543879/pointwise-convergence-is-uniform-convergence-under-some-condition/3544268?noredirect=1#comment7290319_3544268)

[2] A course in metric geometry - Burago, Burago and Ivanov

> **Question :** I want to *understand intuitively or visually* the proof of
>   Theorem 8.5.4 in [2], which is in the below and which seems to be a little technical proof containing *net*-notion (cf. We already considered a continuous case (?) in [1]).
>
> More geometrically, I want to know how pointwise convergence bacomes uniform convergence.

Note that there exists a Riemannian metric $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $G=
\mathbb{Z}^2$-action. Hence from this action, we have a
$G$-invariant metric on the set $G$.

But **without this action, we can define a $G$-invariant metric $d$ on**
$G$ : For instance, $$f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ f(x,y)=|x| -1+
\sum_{i=0}^{|y|}\ \frac{1}{2^i} $$ We set $$
d((x,y),(a,b))=f((x,y)-(a,b))$$

We set $F ((x,y)) = \lim_{n\in\mathbb{N}, \ n\rightarrow \infty}\
\frac{f(n(x,y)) }{ n} $ so that we have a *semi-norm* $\|\ \|$ on $
 \mathbb{R}^2$ which is not a norm and which is an extension of $F$.

Here when we choose $f$ suitably so that $\|\ \|$ is in fact a norm, then prove that given $
\varepsilon$ there is $R$ s.t. $\|(x,y) \| >R
$ implies $|\frac{f ((x,y)) }{\| (x,y) \| } - 1| < \varepsilon $ (cf **Theorem 8.5.4**)

**The Proof in the book :**

**i)** $v=(x,y)$. Note that $f(nv)\leq nf(v)$ That is we have $$
\|\ \|\leq f \leq C\cdot |\ |$$ for some $C>0$ where $|\ |$ is Euclidean norm.

**ii)** Assume that $B$ is $\|\ \|$-unit ball

> Define $S \subset \mathbb{Q}G$ **to be finite $\varepsilon$-net in** $B$

For $v=(x,y)\in S$, there is a natural number $M'$ s.t. $M'v \in G$

Hence there is $M''$ s.t. $Mv=M'' M'v$ and $
| \frac{f(Mv) }{M''} -\| M'v\|| <
 \varepsilon$ for all $v\in S$, since $S$ is a finite set

Hence $$ f(Mv)\leq M\varepsilon +M\|v\|
 \leq M(1+\varepsilon ) $$

For any $w\in G
 $, there is $v$ s.t. $$ \| \frac{w}{\| w\|} -v \| <
 \varepsilon $$

When $k\leq \| w\|< k+1$, then $$
 \| w-\| w\| v \| < \|w\|\varepsilon ,\
  \| w-kv\| \leq  \|w\|\varepsilon +1 $$

Hence \begin{align*} f(Mw) &\leq f(kMv ) + f(kMv - Mw)
 \\&< k(1+ \varepsilon ) M + C\| kv-w\|_E M
 \\&< k(1+\varepsilon  ) M + CC_2 \|kv-w\| M
 \\&< k(1+ \varepsilon )M +CC_2 M\bigg\{ \|w \|
 \varepsilon +1 \bigg\} \end{align*}

Hence there is $k_0$ s.t. $\| w\|>k_0$ implies $|\frac{f(Mw)}{\|
Mw\|} -1|<\varepsilon$

> **iii)** Here when $G'$ is set of $M$-divisible vectors, then
>   $G'$ is a **net**
>   in $G$

Proof : $ (x,y)=(Mq_1+r_1,Mq_2+r_2)$

**iv)** When $F(v)> Mk+2M$, then there is $w$ s.t. $\|v-w\|
<M$

Hence $\|w\|>Mk$ and $\frac{k}{k-1}<1+\varepsilon$ so that $$
\frac{f(v)}{\|v\|}  < \frac{f(w) +f(v-w)}{ \| w\| - M} <
1+2\varepsilon + \frac{cM}{\| w\|-M} $$